# solr result grouping error unexpected docvalues type sorted set for field "recentjobtitlecopy"(expected=SORTED)

Tags: json, xml, solr, schema, solrnet

I am new to solr and wanted to implement document grouping.I am using solr 6.1 version.I have a schema.xml with fields like this :

```xml
<field indexed="true" name="recentjobtitle" omitNorms="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" stored="true" termOffsets="true" termPositions="true" termVectors="true" type="text_general"/>
<field docValues="false" indexed="true" name="recentjobtitlecopy" omitNorms="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false" stored="false" termOffsets="true" termPositions="true" termVectors="true" type="string_ci"/>
```

Here, "recentjobtitle" is a tokenized field so to get the grouped results, I used "recentjobtitlecopy" field.

```
<copyField dest="recentjobtitlecopy" source="recentjobtitle"/>
```

Now, when i ran the group query like this:

```
group=true&group.field=recentjobtitlecopy&group.limit=10
```

I got this exception:solr result grouping error unexpected docvalues type sorted set for field "recentjobtitlecopy"(expected=SORTED).

I even tried to remove "docValues" property on "recentjobtitlecopy" field, performed re-indexing via the Data Import Handler console. Still, the exception was the same.

Strangely, the same code works on my local machine(with and without docValues) solr setup, but throws the exception on a hosted environment(multiple shards here). Can anyone please point out if I am missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: try using plain string as the field type and then use the docValues as tru

Comment: Or it may be because your field is a copy field and then it will be of type array...check if you can avoid it as copyfield

Comment: Only reindexing might not help - you'll probably need to clear out the index completely after changing the type (since the docValues type is common for the whole field). IIRC `SORTED` vs `SORTED_SET` is about the field being multivalued.

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried clearing the indexes and then importing data after removing the docValues property from "recentjobtitlecopy" but still no luck.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I cant remove the copy field as I need it for grouping.

Comment: It's probably not related to docValues (but leaving it out would just set it to the default value, which usually is on - but might not be for the field type you're using); it's related to the field being multiValued. Try setting `multiValued="false"` instead. `string_ci` is multi valued by default iirc.

Comment: @AbhijitBashett It worked with string field. Thank you so much!

Comment: @KanikaSharma, Shall I add it as an answer...The fields should be string and multivalued should be false.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Yeah, you can. Please add not to use a multivalued field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `string` as fieldType for your field named `recentjobtitlecopy`

Do not use the multivalued for your field.

Your field definition would look like below. This is a simple definition of your field. You can add additional attributes as required.

```
<field name="recentjobtitlecopy" type="string" indexed="true" docValues="false" omitNorms="false" stored="false"/>
```